# Computer restarts when I don't turn off the monitors before clicking shutdown (No system error)

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, shutdown, reboot

For quite a while now my Computer keeps restarting when I shut it down. The only way it doesn`t turn on again is to either click the shut down button and then extremly fast turn off the monitor, or run a command that shuts down the PC in some seconds and before it starts turn off the monitors.

When I turn the Monitors on again after it the PC is shut down, it doesn`t restart.
I have Windows 10 and a reinstall of a new version didn't help.

I guess it`s in something in the BIOS but I can't find it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your description, the problem is probably not with Windows.
It may possibly be some installed application, which you can verify by booting in
Safe mode to disable all third-party applications and drivers.

For the BIOS, you may boot into the BIOS and reset it (losing all settings,
so don't do it if you have encrypted the disk).
You may also search for a new BIOS from the website of the manufacturer
of your motherboard, but be very careful since an error in the installation
may brick the computer.

Otherwise, this may be a hardware error, maybe related to the power supply,
and is better handled by a professional.

Comment: I reset the bios and it works now. Weird since I can't remember changing anything in the past. Thanks for your help!